# Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) Estimator of Time Shifts with Poisson Process Prior

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian

Assume that a signal $ y $ is a noisy superposition of time-shifted copies of a given waveform $ f(t) $ on a finite time interval $ [0, T] $:
\begin{equation}
  y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(t - \tau_j) + \eta(t)
\end{equation}
where $ \eta(t) $ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution of variance $ \sigma^2 $ and $ \{ \tau_j \}_{j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}} $ are a Poisson process with rate $ \mu $.

What would be the Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) estimator for $ \theta = \{ \tau_j \}_{j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}} $?

More precisely, by definition of the MAP estimator:
\begin{equation}
  \theta_{MAP} = \underset{\theta}{\arg\max} \; f(y \mid \theta) f(\theta)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
  f(y \mid \theta) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\left\| y(t) - \hat{y}(t) \right\|_2^2}{\sigma^2} \right)
\end{equation}
with:
\begin{equation}
  \hat{y}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(t - \tau_i)
\end{equation}

What would be the expresion of the prior $ f(\theta) $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prior $ f(\theta) $ where $ \theta = \{ \tau_j \}_{j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}} $ are a Poisson process with rate $ \mu $ is given by:
\begin{align}
  f(\theta) &= f_{\tau_{(1)}, \cdots, \tau_{(n)}}(t_1, \cdots, t_n) \\
  & = f_{\tau_{(1)}, \cdots, \tau_{(n)} \mid N(T) = n}(t_1, \cdots, t_n) \times \mathbb{P}(N(T) = n) \\
  & = \frac{n!}{t^n} \mathbb{1}_{\left[ 0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n \leq T \right]} \times \frac{(\mu t)^n}{n!} e^{-\mu t} \\
  & = \mu^n e^{-\mu t} \mathbb{1}_{\left[ 0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n \leq T \right]}
\end{align}
Then if we consider only the "ordered" parameters, the MAP estimator is:
\begin{equation}
  \theta_{MAP} = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\left\| y(t) - \hat{y}(t) \right\|_2^2}{\sigma^2} \right) \mu^n e^{-\mu t}
\end{equation}